# Aws-lambda-php Process exited before completing request

Tags: php, aws-lambda

Error : spawn php-7-bin/bin/php ENOENT 
[image]

[image]

```
  process.env['PATH'] = process.env['PATH'] + ':' + 
  process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'];

 const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

 exports.handler = function(event, context) {

   var php = spawn('php-7-bin/bin/php',['helloLambda.php']);
   var output = "";

   //send the input event json as string via STDIN to php process
   php.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(event));

  //close the php stream to unblock php process
  php.stdin.end();

  //dynamically collect php output
  php.stdout.on('data', function(data) {console.log("data",data);
      output+=data;
});

//react to potential errors
php.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log("STDERR: "+data);
});

//finalize when php process is done.
php.on('close', function(code) {
        context.succeed(JSON.parse(output));
});
}
```

I tried giving these possible paths :

```
'php-7-bin/bin/php' (as in doc)<br>
'./php-7-bin/bin/php'<br>
'~/php-7-bin/bin/php'<br>
'/php-7-bin/bin/php'<br>
'php'
```

This is the doc I followed : 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scripting-languages-for-aws-lambda-running-php-ruby-and-go/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error clearly specifies 'No such directory entry'.
I tried printing current working directory.

```
console.log(process.cwd()); /ouptput : 'var/task'.
```

Then changed php path to

```
  var php = spawn('/var/task/php-lambda/php-7-bin/bin/php',['/var/task/php-lambda/helloLambda.php']);
```